# Electrical circuit at t>0 and t<0

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm getting confused here about the sign of the V on the capacitor.

Why is it \$-I_0 \times R\$ and nor \$I_0 \times R\$?

[image]

note that the second circuit is at t=0+.

Comment: Seems wrong to me too..

Comment: @EugeneSh. My lecturer was very sure of himself.. that what is confusing me! And he got a correct answer at the end.

Comment: Wierd. T>0 and T<0 is the same as T != 0, so this is a dynamic event. Time is always in motion, so the charge on C is constantly changing. For a time-constant function, the extra math seems over-kill. Is there a goal here?

Comment: I figured it out: If you make KVL it will be true.

Comment: @SijaanHallak, If you resolved the issue, please post an answer. That will avoid the system periodically bringing the question to the front page looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use KVL you will get :

\$Vr+Vc=0\$

\$Vr=-Vc\$

when \$Vr= I_0\times R  \rightarrow Vc =-I_0 \times R \$

Answer (score 0):

Take into consideration that inductor at t < 0 changes into a wire with R = 0 . Hence the voltage across the C ( Vc ) will be equal to the resistors voltage . By the given direction for the current , it will be negative as you have shown in the formula .